# Is there an easy way to remember Invoker's spells?

Tags: dota-2

I've begun to play Invoker more since he's fun to play (I'd probs get a bite to eat with him also). However, it takes some time to learn the combinations for his spells. I believe I will learn them all in time, but is there an easier, faster way to learn them (maybe a mnemonic method or something along those lines)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Play this until you get your time down to 10 seconds or so: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/75495922/InvokerTrainer.htm

Then play a bot game or two until you're confident with your hero and your build, and you should be fine jumping into a real game at your skill level. The hero is definitely hard to play, but he's not nearly as hard as people pretend he is because he's so damned good at everything.

The skillbuild most commonly used right now:

QRQEEEREQQW

Q first for regen, R for Cold Snap, then another Q should give you plenty of regen in lane. Then you level E four times (getting Invoke when possible), followed by Q twice more. This puts you at 4-0-4-2, which allows you to summon double Forge Spirits as early as possible. This combined with Cold Snap is absolutely devastating at low levels- you will melt through armor and with three Exort orbs up you'll hit tremendously hard. From there you get a point in Wex to open up the rest of your spellbook (notably Ghost Walk). Typically you max E first, then W, to get the most casting power.

The typical item build:

- Starting items: Claw of Attack, Iron Branch, Healing Salve
- Early items: Phase Boots, then Drum, then Force Staff
- Midgame items: Aghanim's Scepter. You want to be finishing this right as you hit level 17.
- Luxury items: Sheepstick, Blink Dagger, Desolator, BKB, Eul's. All situational.

If you're interested in learning basics about the hero, I did a relatively popular walkthrough a few months back that goes over the old Quas-Wex build that was popular at the time. We didn't touch much on the Quas-Exort build that I've described above, though, and that QE style is much more popular recently due to a buff in the most recent balance patch. Video:

Comment: Could you skip the iron branch to save toward the bracer?

Comment: I think the 53 gold is easily worth what a branch gives you. Inventory slots are typically very valuable, so throughout most of the game, your inventory should be as close to full as possible unless there's a very specific reason otherwise. If you prefer rushing the Bracer instead of Phase Boots, try the start shown in the video (+3 STR, circlet, branch, tangoes, salve).

Comment: @challen If you had an infinitely sized inventory, iron branches are actually the best items in the game due to their cost vs. benefit ratio. Branches are always worth it early on the game, even if you don't plan on building a magic wand.

Answer (score 6):

There is a flash game where you can practice and learn faster the combinations. The game is "Invoker" and can be found at http://www.invokergame.com/

Practice is always a great way to get the feeling of the gameplay

Answer (score 2):

For me, I connect each spells to their respective elements;

Meteor : EEW : Major fire EE + travel W

Forge Spirit : Major fire EE + life essence Q

Sun Strike : Sun is pure fire so EEE

Ghost walk : Major cold QQ + slow travel W

Ice wall : Major cold QQ + Damage E

Cold snap : pure chilling power so QQQ

Alacrity : Major speed WW + Damage E

Tornado : Wind blast so WW + tornado is cold Q (I believe there's no hot tornado :))

EMP :  Pure WWW just because it's less likely to mix up with another element than Tornado and Alacrity :D

Answer (score 2):

You should give a try to our Invoker build creation page:

http://www.buildota2.com/build_creation?hero_name=invoker

Press the "?" button, set the desired level in one click and play with elements. You can level up core skills by clicking on them or simply press "Q", "W", "E" to level up elements and "R" to level up Invoke like it is in the game.
Allowed abilities become colorful and you can get detailed information about them by tooltips. You can hold mouse over any ability and update the elements using keyboard to see how ability parameters evolve on the fly.
Also you can fit any items to see how they update the Invoker characteristics as it is the common for all heroes feature.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add couple of tips in addition to the answers given by Decency and Wint. These are the tips I my self discovered by looking at the tools they both provided and I successfully implemented.

**Write it down**

Write down the skills on the paper. Yes, this is oldest tradition of memorizing something. This has helped me so much personally. I first tried to stright away testing my skills in the voker skill tools. But later I realized its like a test which I need to come prepare so I first tried to memorized them by one of this traditional method which is successful in my case

**Slow and focused learning:**

What that means, myself just like many newbie vokers trid to memorize all 10 skills but..... As a general game play we build skills only two of the elements utill level 10-11 i.e; quas/wex, quas/exort or wex/exort. So it is good thing to focus on learning the skill build which you prefer to build. Since the popular builds are quas/exort and quas/wex, pick one of the builds and learn the skills combination of two skills only.

Say you have chosen to build Quas/Exort build then you level up only QE until level 10-11 then you will be able to cast only Cold Snap, Ice Wall, Sun Strike and Forge Sprite, try to memorize these 4 skills and 2 are easy to remember with QQQ and EEE now just need to memorize only two more.

Similarly, if you choose Quas/Wex build then you will cast only Cold Snap, Ghost Walk, Emp and Tornado, again 2 skills are straight to remember QQQ and WWW and leaves you with 2 more skills to memorize which is lot easy.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using the ‘[Invoker Game](http://www.invokergame.com/)’ as mentioned by others as a test, I like to come up with ridiculous (the more ridiculous the better!) explanations for each spell combination based on the elements associated with Quas (ice/water), Wex (air/wind) and Exort (fire). For example:

- **Cold Snap** freezes the target, therefore requiring lots of ice (Quas): **QQQ**
- **Chaos Meteor** is known for its firey power (Exort), but can only burn up on entering the atmosphere because of friction with the air (Wex): **EEW**
- **Alacrity** makes people move faster (Wex gives movement/attack speed), and setting people on fire also encourages them to run faster (Exort): **WWE**